# pass multiple data as a list to View in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, view

How to pass LINQ data to View. I have used below code but it throwing conversion error.

```
namespace WebApplication1.DataContext
{
    public class Repositary
    {
        public  ProductMaster productMaster { get; set; }
        public  ProductDetail productDetail { get; set; }
    }
}`
```

**Action Method:-**

```
public ActionResult ProductMasterWithDetails()
{
    Model1 db=new Model1();
    Repositary rep = new Repositary();
    var varResult= from pm in db.ProductMasters join pd in db.ProductDetails on pm.ProductId equals pd.ProductId select new  { pm.ProductId, pm.ProductName, pd.Price, pd.ManufactureBy };

    ViewBag.result = varResult.ToList();

    return View();
}
```

> Error: Cannot initialize type 'WebApplication1.DataContext.Repositary'
>   with a collection initializer because it does not implement
>   'System.Collections.IEnumerable'
>   C:\Users\msnsh\onedrive\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\Controllers\ProductController.cs    55  141 WebApplication1

**In View:**

```
@foreach (var result in  ViewBag.result){

}
```

I have two model classes as follows.

```
namespace WebApplication1.DataContext
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

    [Table("ProductMaster")]
    public partial class ProductMaster
    {
        public ProductMaster()
        {
            ProductDetails = new HashSet<ProductDetail>();
        }

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string ProductName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ProductDetail> ProductDetails { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace WebApplication1.DataContext
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

    public partial class ProductDetail
    {
        public int? Price { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string ManufactureBy { get; set; }

        public int? ProductId { get; set; }

        [Key]
        public int ProdDetailsId { get; set; }

        public virtual ProductMaster ProductMaster { get; set; }
    }
}
```

If we have two model classes then how to replace below single Model namespace  ?

@model IEnumerable

I cannot create a single class as below, because my model has two classes,

```
public Class ProductCustomModel
   {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int ProductName { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public int ManufactureBy { get; set; }
   }
```

Here is my Model1 Class.

```
namespace WebApplication1.DataContext
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;
    public partial class Model1 : DbContext
    {
        public Model1()
            : base("name=Model1")
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<ProductDetail> ProductDetails { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ProductMaster> ProductMasters { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<ProductDetail>()
                .Property(e => e.ManufactureBy)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ProductMaster>()
                .Property(e => e.ProductName)
                .IsUnicode(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a view model containing those 4 properties, the project the query to the view model (not an anonymous object). The return that collection to the view (you view will have `@model List<yourModel>` (do not use `ViewBag`)

Comment: Can you please give a sample code how to do?

Comment: Your sample code is unclear, what is the `Model1` class and why have you initialized `rep` variable which is not used anywhere?

Comment: Model1 is EntityName

Comment: @ShakeerHussain The exception is clearly about the `Repository` class. Are you trying to assign the linq query values to `rep` variable without field name initializer? I think the sample code you have posted is different from the code in your application?

Comment: Hi Vijay, Yes am trying to assign the Linq query values to varResult.

Comment: Don't add your question in the Answer..!!

Comment: **Please stop posting additional information as answers!** Use the [edit] link below your question to add additional information *to the question*. Use the answers only to post an actual answer to the question. Please read about [ask] and [answer].

Answer (score 1):

**If you getdata in varResult than you should try,**

**In Conroller.**

```
    Model1 db=new Model1();

    var varResult= (from pm in db.ProductMasters join pd in db.ProductDetails on pm.ProductId equals pd.ProductId select new  { pm.ProductId, pm.ProductName, pd.Price, pd.ManufactureBy }).ToList();
    return View("path to the view",varResult);
```

**In View**

```
    @model ModelName
    @foreach (var result in  Model){

    }
```

Comment: what is your Model1.

Answer (score 0):

You should need to change the `ViewBag` to the `customModel/Class` which will send the `List` to your view.

**Models:**

```
namespace WebApplication1.DataContext
{
    public class Repositary
    {
        public  ProductMaster productMaster { get; set; }
        public  ProductDetail productDetail { get; set; }
    }

   public Class ProductCustomModel
   {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int ProductName { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public int ManufactureBy { get; set; }
   }
}
```

**Change your action Method to this:**

```
public ActionResult ProductMasterWithDetails()
{
    Model1 db=new Model1();
    Repositary rep = new Repositary();
    var varResult= from pm in db.ProductMasters join pd in db.ProductDetails on pm.ProductId equals pd.ProductId select new  { pm.ProductId, pm.ProductName, pd.Price, pd.ManufactureBy };

    //Make your List Here like this and add the values in it.
    List<ProductCustomModel> productCustomModelList = new List<ProductCustomModel>(); 
    Foreach(ProductCustomModel item in varResult)
    {
          ProductCustomModel singleData = new ProductCustomModel();

          ProductId = item.ProductId,
          ProductName = item.ProductName,
          Price = item.Price,
          ManufactureBy = item.ManufactureBy

          productCustomModelList.Add(singleData);
    }
    return View(productCustomModelList);
```

}

**In the View(.cshtml)**

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.DataContext.ProductCustomModel>
@foreach (var result in  Model){
    //.. operations
}
```